# Put PNG over a JPG in PHP

Tags: php, image, image-processing, gd

I want to do the following in PHP:

I have two images, a jpg and a png. I want to resize the jpg to the same size as the png then put the png on top.  The PNG has transparency so I would like to preserve that so the jpg shows underneath.

If anyone could help that would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Look into the GD (or GD2) library for PHP.

Comment: i want to achieve this in woocommerce can someone direct

Comment: It is not duplicate. It is another approach.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
<?
$png = imagecreatefrompng('./mark.png');
$jpeg = imagecreatefromjpeg('./image.jpg');

list($width, $height) = getimagesize('./image.jpg');
list($newwidth, $newheight) = getimagesize('./mark.png');
$out = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
imagecopyresampled($out, $jpeg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
imagecopyresampled($out, $png, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $newwidth, $newheight);
imagejpeg($out, 'out.jpg', 100);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Stuck on the similar merging issue for 3rd day without any ideas (*forgot everything what knew before*) ... saved my *soul*! Great thanks! God bless you!

Comment: Code is not working. As it displays image not found icon.

Comment: Great answer, solution works well.

Answer (score 7):

This is the working code which i using

```
$dest = imagecreatefrompng('mapCanvas.png');
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg('si.jpg');
imagealphablending($dest, false);
imagesavealpha($dest, true);
// Copy and merge
imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 17, 13, 0, 0, 60, 100, 100);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
```

Comment: Thks it is working perfectly but output image have n colours means it outputs black-white image. Now what to do for it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link to an example that will overlay a transparent watermark onto an image. Might be your use case, might be related.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples.merged-watermark.php

There is also a way to load JPG images, resize images, turn on alpha tracking, and export images in GD.

Jacob