# Insert PNG with alpha channel using FPDF (PHP)

Tags: php, png, fpdf

In official documentation of FPDF, it said alpha channel is not supported for PNG.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to put a transparent image on top of another: use PHPs build in functions to copy one image onto the other one. Then you will end up with a new picture, containing boths images. Save as a non-alpha png, and insert.

There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269363/put-png-over-a-jpg-in-php) of the code needed to combine the images.

If you want text to be visible under you picture: insert the picture first, then write you text into the document.

Answer (score 5):

Try this extension for FPDF:

http://valentin.dasdeck.com/php/fpdf/fpdf_alpha/

Short description from the page:

> This script allows to use images (PNGs
>   or JPGs) with alpha-channels. The
>   alpha-channel can be either supplied
>   as separate 8-bit PNG ("mask"), or,
>   for PNGs, also an internal
>   alpha-channel can be used. For the
>   latter, the GD 2.x extension is
>   required.
>
> Specifying a separate mask image has
>   several advantages:
>   - no GD required.
>   - Better quality (full 8-bit alpha channel, whereas GD internally only
>   supports 7-bit alpha channels)
>   - much faster (extraction of embedded alpha-channel has to be done
>   pixel-wise)
>
> function Image(string file, float x,
>   float y [, float w [, float h [,
>   string type [, mixed link [, boolean
>   isMask [, int maskImg]]]]]])
>
> Same parameters as for original
>   Image()-method, with 2 additional
>   (optional) parameters: isMask: if
>   specified and true, the image is used
>   as mask for other images. In this
>   case, the parameters x, y, w and h
>   will be ignored and the mask image
>   itself is not visible on the page.
>   maskImg: number of image resource (as
>   returned by previously called Image()
>   with isMask parameter set to true)
>   that will be used as mask for this
>   image.
>
> function ImagePngWithAlpha(string
>   file, float x, float y [, float w [,
>   float h [, mixed link]]])
>
> Same parameters as for original
>   Image()-method, but without a type
>   parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me thanks folks. I basically included the extension above (http://valentin.dasdeck.com/php/fpdf/fpdf_alpha/) and then extended classes as follows:

In fpdf_tpl.php
    require('PDF_ImageAlpha.php');

```
class FPDF_TPL extends PDF_ImageAlpha
```

In PDF_ImageAlpha.php:

```
class PDF_ImageAlpha extends FPDF{
Inside of here I chaged the image() function to F_image() to avoid clashing (probably       should have used namespaces). With a quick search and replace you will see that this needs replacing 2 more times.
}
```

Then in my workhorse.php file I called the function F_image() instead of image() and this fixed my issue.

Thanks!!!